# Android Web View does not refresh after UI change is done from loadURL from onPageFinished function

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

```
public static String abc;
public static WebView webview;
public static String response;
public String urls = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


            System.out.println(urls);

            urls += " \n" + url;
            try {
                view.loadUrl("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value= '8';}) ();");
                view.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){document.getElementById('fpId').value = 2454344344; })();");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");




            }catch (Exception e){

                System.out.println(e);
```

After `view.loadUrl` is executed on the view Object , the HTML string returned is having the modified data but the page rendered in the webview does not changes .
Plus,

```
view.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value= '8';}) ();"); ---- would modify the change successfully in the HTML ( not rendered back to the webview still)
```

but the :

```
view.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){document.getElementById('fpId').value = '2454344344'; })();"); ---- would not even change the value field .
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Thanks , user392117 for the Edit .

Comment: From Android 4.4 (API level 19) and above, you should use the method `evaluateJavascript()` to run JavaScript asynchronously.